# How to force Javapoet to create UTF-8 Java source code?

Tags: java, javapoet

Is there a way to write a `com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile` to the file system and make sure the file always is encoded using `UTF-8`?

Currently I am using `com.squareup.javapoet.JavaFile#writeTo(java.io.File dir)` but this uses the default encoding of the current virtual machine.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked in javapoet issue tracker?

Comment: It's not a bug but a simple question therefore I don't want to file an issue for it. But I will file an issue for introducing a simpler way to create Java source code with a specific encoding.

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/square/javapoet/issues/564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Github-Page of Javapoet, you can use the Method:

```
JavaFile.writeTo(PrintStream)
```

So you should be able to create a PrintStream using UTF-8 und write the file like this:

```
PrintStream stream = new PrintStream("YourTargetFile.java", "UTF-8");
yourJavaFileObject.writeTo(stream);
```

Comment: I was looking at the https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/README.md but was not able to find a documentation about it. Thanks a lot. This works perfect. Nevertheless it has the downside, that you have to name Java file and create all it package directories yourself.

Comment: It wasn't really that clear from the README, but I saw that JavaFile.writeTo(System.out) was used and since that's an PrintStream I knew that this will work.
Another possible way would be the use JavaFile.toString() and write the resulting String into a File manually.

Comment: I will file an issue to introduce a new `writeTo(File directory, Charset encoding)` method for convenience.